# How to create folder in parent directory?

Tags: php, mkdir

My php script is located in **`/var/www/html/users/dev`**. I need to create a folder in **`/var/www/images/`** - something like `/var/www/images/test/test/` and store here some images.

But when i trying is with `mkdir($file_dir, 0777);` where `$file_dir` is **`/var/www/images/test/test/`** i receive an error:

> Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/users/dev/classes/sites.class.php...

Comment: either permissions or you have to set `true` as third parameters to recursively create it.

Comment: If using windows [see this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php#53075)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `"/var/www/images/test"` does not exists, so you can not `mkdir("/var/www/images/test/test")`

You can specify the `"$recursive"` to `TRUE`, and it will work, like this:

`mkdir($file_dir, 0777, TRUE);`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
mkdir($file_dir, 0777, true);
```

The third parameter ('recursive') allows you to specify a path of which all directories will be created. If you don't, only the last directory ('test') will be created, and the whole path before that must exist.

The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) is quite clear about that.

Answer (score 1):

if it is Linux you have set permissions to your parent directory 1st.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /path of ur directory.
```